# VBA Export to PDF produces a very large PDF File

Tags: c#, vba, excel, pdf

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:="file_path", _
    Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I am trying to export an excel sheet to PDF with VBA. The excel sheet is filled with time series charts. The PDF created by VBA is too large for email (90mb). Is there a way to export to a smaller file size? I have tried changing quality to "xlQualityMinimum" but there was no change in file size.

Alternatively, I could compress the PDF in C#. But I can't find a free way to do this. If outputting a smaller file in VBA is not possible, does anyone know how to compress in C#?

Comment: Could this be compressed using VBA, or does C# need to play a roll?

Comment: @Brandon: C# doesn't need to play a role, it can be compressed in either language.

Comment: How many pages in the PDF?

Comment: @TimWilliams: In total the PDF has 117 pages, but because export the excel sheet to PDF took up so much memory, I broke the 117 pages into 6 PDF files, about 20 pages each.

Comment: Do you have "ISO19005-1 Compliant" checked (it's in the "options" dialog when you're exporting)  If I turn that off the file is smaller.  See: http://superuser.com/questions/645657/export-word-document-with-high-resolution-png-to-pdf

Comment: @TimWilliams He's mentioned he's exporting via VBA, not manually via the excel save as or export dialog. Are you aware of any way to indicate to the Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat VBA method that ISO 19005-1 compliance is not required (and presumably hence that it can take shortcuts that will result in a non-compliant, but more compressed file)

Comment: @Blair - this link has a registry key which could be used to control compliance:  https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2016&Policy=office16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_EnforcePDFcompliancewithISO190051PDFA

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using VBA already, you should look into compressing your PDF using 7zip. It is free and can be started from the command line. Here is a link where you can find the source; http://www.7-zip.org/

Using the macro provided below you will be able to navigate and zip individual files. Depending on your preference you'll need to adjust it to make it fit your needs.

```
Sub ZipFiles()
   Dim src  As Variant
   Dim dst  As Variant
   Dim file As Variant

   Const PATH_TO_7Z = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

   Set src = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Source folder", &H245)
   If Not src Is Nothing Then
      src = src.Self.Path & "\"

      Set dst = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Destination folder", &H245)
      If Not dst Is Nothing Then
         dst = dst.Self.Path & "\"

         For Each file In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(src).Files
            Shell PATH_TO_7Z & " a -tzip """ & dst & file.Name & ".zip"" """ & file.Path & """"
         Next
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Otherwise if your source and destination folders are constant, you could do something like this.

```
Sub ZipFiles()
   Dim file As Variant

   Const SOURCE     = "C:\test\source"
   Const DEST       = "C:\test\destination"
   Const PATH_TO_7Z = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

   For Each file In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(SOURCE).Files
      Shell PATH_TO_7Z & " a -tzip """ & DEST & "\" & file.Name & ".zip"" """ & file.Path & """"
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. My word choice (compressed) was poor. Unfortunately the final product needs to be a PDF file instead of a zip file so that the email attachment can be opened and viewed on mobile devices. I need a way to reduce PDF quality.